# `Sender address rejected: not owned by user` in Postfix

Tags: postfix

I am getting the following error when I try to send an email from a client on my home computer through my authenticated SMTP server, to `receiver@gmail.com`.

```
Oct 17 09:21:40 debian postfix/smtpd[1643]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from
unknown[x.x.x.x]: 553 5.7.1 <sender@example.com>: Sender address rejected:
not owned by user sender@example.com; from=<sender@example.com>
to=<receiver@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.5]>
```

I'm ultimately looking for a fix for the error, but I'm currently wondering what configuration parameters in `main.cf` are able to fix it. For example, should I fiddle with `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`?
I am unable to remove the error by making any of the previous parameters as permissive as possible.

**Edit:** Here is the relevant part of my current configuration, although I am mainly looking for a couple possible Postfix parameters that could be causing the address to be rejected.

```
relay_domains = *

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
```

And in `master.cf`:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

Comment: It would help if you could post your current configuration.

Comment: Those error came from this restriction [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch)

Comment: @masegaloeh Thanks. Although it seems to be the one, I removed that line from `master.cf`, and the error still prevails.

Comment: just clarification: Did you restart postfix after edit `master.cf`?

Comment: Yes, but that question prodded me to think outside of the box and find a rather uninteresting bug in the scripts which are deploying my postfix configuration edits. My `master.cf` file was being copied to a location other than `/etc/postfix/master.cf`. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 12):

According to the manual [smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) need to be set. Setting it to the same value as [virtual_mailbox_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps) worked for me. E.g.:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps    = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
```

Also, if your maps live in a database, keep in mind you need to actually select a field, not just "1" like some howtos are suggesting.

```
# good
query = SELECT email FROM postfix_mailbox_maps where email = '%s';

# bad
query = SELECT 1 FROM postfix_mailbox_maps where email = '%s';
```

Comment: Your "one more thing" is worth it's weight in gold. I spent hours and hours trying to figure out the issue when the query just had to be modified slightly. Is this do to a change in Postfix? Any docs?

Comment: Thanks, that nearly fixed it for me. Your solution works only when the "username" and "maildir" colums contain identical data. But my maildirs look like domain/local_part, so i had to copy mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf and change

`select_field = maildir

to

select_field = username`

Answer (score 2):

Add this:
smtpd_sender_restrictions = **permit_sasl_authenticated** in the main.cf

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which is how my server is configured (if your domain is not "virtual", find the correspond options) :

Keep existing options as they were on your initial question, I don't think they are the problem.

Add this in main.cf :

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-users
```

/etc/postfix/virtual (probably not relevant to you) :

```
sender@exemple.com    sender@exemple.com
other@exemple.com     other@exemple.com
alias@exemple.com     sender@exemple.com
```

/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-domains

```
exemple.com    OK
```

/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-users (This is the important part)

```
sender@exemple.com    sender@exemple.com
other@exemple.com     other@exemple.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem with one user on a server being unable to send e-mails, but all other users could. I found out that that user wasn't added in Alias table in postfix DB so keep that in mind and check all tables in postfix DB. That solved problem for me.

Answer (score -4):

Change to
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
           remove             #permit_mynetworks,.

Comment: We're looking for longer answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.